# The type com.ibm.mq.MQException cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: java, eclipse, mq

I am getting a compilation error in eclipse Juno....

```
The type com.ibm.mq.MQException cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

I am using java 1.6

Can anyone tell me how to resolve this?

Answer (score 4):

Add the library containing said class into your classpath.

com.ibm.mq.MQException [is in com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar in MQ 7](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21316673).

Comment: @user1407668 then you should verify a) does the jar you've added contain that class (it's a .zip, you can just open it) and b) did you really add it to classpath correctly (you can print your full classpath)

Comment: Should I unzip that in the classpath?

Comment: @user1407668 no, you should not. That's not what I said. You should open it and verify yourself that it contains the class.

Comment: @user1407668 As eis mentioned, first check the manifest if the version is v7 & check the existence of the class. You can get the client jars [IBM v7 Client](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24019253)

Comment: Hi.. I tried printing the classpath and com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar.zip is there in the classpath. But still I get the error